# Sound does not work?

Tags: 11.10, sound

Ok, yesterday the sound worked great, both the internal speakers and my headphones. But today it doesn't work at all. I cant find out what the problem is, I tried with rebooting the system and log in and out. My sound card is a ATI sound card, and the speakers are RV710 i think. I would be really glad if I could get some help. If it matters i use Ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 1):

As you happen to know your Hardware why don't you give this a try?

Click on the volume icon and go to sound preferences.
Under the hardware tab, select the correct hardware in case it has changed.

[image]

Under the output tab select the same thing you selected in the hardware tab.

[image]

Lastly see if anything is muted. If so un-mute it. :)

Comment: Once U've selected the right Hardware, use the 'Test Speakers' Option to test if u are getting any sound. If you don't hear anything  U haven't selected the right one.

Comment: If none of these work.. give this Wiki page a read https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingSoundProblems

Comment: Oh the speaker was mute, I'm feeling quite stupid, but anyway thanks really much for the help! :D

Comment: It Happens.. :)

Comment: I have made the above changes as well, and I get sound, but upon reboot, all the settings revert to the "internal audio" default. It still doesn't save the changes I make.