# Why does Providesupport Chat Console not produce event sounds?

Tags: sound

I am using Providesupport Chat Console from providesupport.com on ubuntu 12.10.

First of all, it crashes sometime :( but thats okay.

The real problem is: It is not producing event sounds. It says `supported playback system is not available`.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can I suggest that you start with this previous question/response: http://askubuntu.com/questions/75732/sound-does-not-work?rq=1

Comment: Hello Mordoc, Sound is working fine for websites, youtube, totem, vlc, ubuntu own sounds, etc.

Comment: I notice that their Linux support page references some pretty old versions of Linux. Could it be possible that it is looking for the OSS sound drivers? It appears that they have been deprecated: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenSound. You could use ProvideSupport's web console which might be as functional...

Comment: Their web console does not allow me to put away :(

Comment: Is it possible if I get the functionality in 12.10 which they are looking for? Like decoupling puleaudio and install their required sound framework such as ALSA or Gstreamer

Comment: Apparently you can at the expense of a possibly hobbled sound system on Linux. Can't really blame Ubuntu for this, OSS has passed out of use some time ago.

Comment: Thank your Mordoc, Just after a smoke, I tried to use their windows version with wine. guess what! It rocks :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To those looking for solution:

Simply install playonlinux from software center.

download the windows executable and run it. it works like a charm and sound works great as well as pop ups.

The only issue I face now is your backspace key and arrow keys. Enter also does not send message and you have to press send button manually.

Work around:

> 1. Right client on providesupport desktop icon (shortcut) and click on properties.
> 2. add this in command: XMODIFIERS=''

Make sure it is single colon two times after =